# Materialize Forms Accepting links

Tags: javascript, html, forms, materialize

I use materialize often and ran into a little issue within one of my apps.  To make it simple I want to basically include a link within a form input (materialize) that will send into a chat feature I made.  When generating the tag, the form cannot read the text (because it is rejecting the html generated link format presumably).  Does anyone knowledgable of forms with materialize know if forms can accept links and if so what kind of format or special script I would need to include to make the form accept text in the form of a link.  It could be another issue as well.  Any input would be appreciated!

Code in question:

```
 // function for pre-filling the information in the modal on the chat button press
function handleChatForm() {
    $.get("/api/user_data", {}, function(data) {

        $('#sender-name').val(data.firstName);
        $('.sender-name-label').addClass('active');
    });

    var currentChatNote = $(this).closest('.addedNoteRow').data("note");
    console.log(currentChatNote);
    console.log(currentChatNote.title);
    var noteObjectForChat = {
        title: currentChatNote.title,
        body: currentChatNote.body
    };
    var noteLink = $('<a>');
    noteLink.data('noteObject', noteObjectForChat);
    noteLink.attr("href", "/cms");
    noteLink.append(currentChatNote.title);
    $('#new-message-body').val(noteLink)
    $('.new-message-label').addClass('active');
}

/** Listener for send button to push data into firebase **/
sendButton.on('click', function() {
    var msgName = nameInput.val().trim();
    var msgText = textInput.val().trim();

    myFirebase.push({ Name: msgName, Text: msgText });
    textInput.val("");
});
```

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Comment: Code was added.  First function I am attempting to pre fill the form with the information needed.  The new-message-body is where I am attempting to add a link to it (materialize form inputs).  The second function is just sending to firebase chat.  When loaded in its current state the input comes back with an array: "[object object]" not in hyperlink form and just as plain text, obviously.